# symfony2 EntityType with extra field

Tags: symfony

Hi I would like to create form like this in symfony [image: form]

I can create a checkbox with parts will be data from database but how can i add textType ? I need each part in my parts table has text type to enter quantity.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. ;-) But we'not here to do the work for you. Have you tried anything? did you any research in symfony's docs?

Comment: I create three entities Product, Component, ProductComponent, in ProductComponent I have fields for Product, Component and quantity.

I am looking for solve not for code, temporary I use 'CollectionType' with entry_type = ProductComponentType which contain select to choose component and textfield to choose quantity but I want to change it to list of checkbox with field for quantity

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your main entity is car. **Car** have **many parts**. If you want to build form, witch allow to add parts to the car, then you are looking for [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) /*This is example code, it is not production ready!*/

If you want to add additional field (not entity property), then you are looking for `mapped` option. See [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped) . May be easiest solution will be to [use listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) . Listener should have logic: after every checkBox add new textBox